# Ruby and Rails insider docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Ruby on Rails application that is running is building with docker.  I run the `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` commands without issue.  It spins up the images and runs puma as expected.

The gems installed are just `rails 6.1.5.1` and `puma 5.6.4`

Here is the output of the `docker-compose up`:

```
my_app   | ENVIRONMENT: development
my_app   | The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
my_app   | => Booting Puma
my_app   | => Rails 6.1.5.1 application starting in development
my_app   | => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
my_app   | Puma starting in single mode...
my_app   | * Puma version: 5.6.4 (ruby 3.0.4-p208) ("Birdie's Version")
my_app   | *  Min threads: 5
my_app   | *  Max threads: 5
my_app   | *  Environment: development
my_app   | *          PID: 9
my_app   | * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
my_app   | Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

However, if I run the following command:

```
docker-compose run --rm my_app rails db:drop db:create db:migrate;
```

I get the following error:

```
ENVIRONMENT: development
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
Could not find rails-6.1.5.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

If I run:

```
docker-compose run --rm my_app sh
```

It drops me to a shell prompt.  From this prompt, I type `rails --version` it returns the proper version of `Rails 6.1.5.1`.  If I run, `rails db:drop`, I get the following:

```
Could not find rails-6.1.5.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

If I run `gem list rails`, it shows a list of rails libraries with the proper version:

```
rails (6.1.5.1)
sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
```

Anyone encounter a problem like this?

Comment: Probably because your bundle happens in your command and overriding it means it does not happen anymore. A pure guess since you are not sharing us the Dockerfile you are using, which is a quite import part to answer your question here.

Comment: Can you put your docker-compose file too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

1. Install the corresponding ruby version on your pc in a native way (without docker)
2. Run `bundle install` this will update your Gemfile.lock
3. Try to build your image again by running `docker-compose build --no-cache`